# Akka: Sharing state across actor instances

Tags: java, akka

My `MyProcessingActor` actor will be routed using a `ConsistentHashingRouter` on an entity ID, such that there may be multiple instances of this actor in process at any one time (across multiple threads)

The actor uses a map to perform some calculation logic. Therefore, 2 different actor instances could be reading and writing to this map at the same time.

Sharing a map across these actor instances seems like a blatant violation of the actor model, even if it is a Java `ConcurrentHashMap`.

What are the best options for dealing with this kind of problem? I didn't see it addressed in the ***Akka*** documentation, unless I missed this.

I can see 2 options:

1. a single instance of a `MyMapManagerActor` that will manage reading/writing to this map. If this is single threaded though then effectively `MyProcessingActor` would be singlethreaded as well
2. use of the Akka STM - I do not see this though in the latest version of the project

What other recommended approaches are there?

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience with Akka, but have been looking into it.  What you describe does seem to be very against the paradigm Akka intends to fit into.   Maybe you could pass the routing map in the message and make it immutable.  The map should also be made immutable as well if you're passing it.

Comment: have you looked at Akka Agents? They may help solve this type of problem http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/agents.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this seems to be a quite difficult thing to do in Akka. Creating an actor to manage access to a map proves quite cumbersome, and STM doesn't seem to be supported in the latest versions.

Therefore, the solution here was to choose the key for the `ConsistentHashingRouter` carefully such that there would never be any race conditions when reading from and writing to a map. The map in question is a `ConcurrentHashMap`

Answer (score 2):

As you said in your question, sharing mutable state between actors is a very bad thing. I have used both approaches that you mention (using something like a `MapManagerActor` and using Akka STM) and both can work, although the `MapManagerActor` approach feels better to me. As far as the `MapManagerActor` is concerned, the only parts that are serialized are the actual reads and writes to the Map, not the calculations themselves, so depending on your use case, you might find that the parallelization is adequate.

Another option would be to replace the Map itself with Actors. You could have one parent actor that manages the children, and one child of that Actor per Map entry. If your set of keys is static, you could pre-create all the child Actors on startup, using, for example, the key (or a hashcode thereof) as the actor name. Then you could use `actorSelection` to access the child Actor directly, as in `/user/parentActor/<key>`. If the actors need to be created dynamically, it would be best to ask the parent actor for a specific child, and have it reply with an `ActorRef` to that specific child (creating it if necessary). Something like:

```
override def receive = {
  case GetActor(key) =>
    context.children(key) match {
      case Some(ref) => sender ! GetActorReply(ref)
      case None => sender ! context.actorOf(ChildActor.props, key)
    }
  }
}
```

The `MyProcessingActor` could then use that `ActorRef` for all its processing.

Answer (score 0):

When an Actor actually runs, it runs as a `Runnable` on a some Executor. The trick to run a set of cooperating actors sequentially is to provide each such set of actors with a dedicated serial executor - see [my answer to the corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32037844/how-to-execute-tasks-in-executorservice-sequentially/46995312#46995312).

Answer (score -3):

If the map is a field on the Actor instance, then there will be two maps and no cross-threading issues will occur.  If the map is shared but read-only, then you are still ok. If the map is shared and both actors write to it, then you definitely need locking using the ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: You didn't really answer the question here, just repeated what the question already stated.  "What other recommended approaches are there?"

Comment: That's correct. What I was pointing out was that there is no conflict if the maps are not being shared. So there is no need for an alternate approach. And if the map is to be shared, then a ConcurrentMap would be the right way to go.

Comment: These are shared: Therefore, 2 different actor instances could be reading and writing to this map at the same time.