# How to execute tasks in ExecutorService sequentially?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have three threads that are joined, i.e. the second thread executes after the first dies.

This is the code I have:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        final Thread thrdA = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Message 1"));
        final Thread thrdB = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Message 2"));
        final Thread thrdC = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("Message 3"));

        thrdA.start();
        thrdA.join();
        thrdB.start();
        thrdB.join();
        thrdC.start();
        thrdC.join();

    }
}
```

How would I implement this functionality using `ExecutorService` instead of three thread objects?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If what you want/need is to execute a group of jobs one after another but in a single thread different that the main app thread, then use [`Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--).

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
es.submit(() -> System.out.println("Message 1"));
es.submit(() -> System.out.println("Message 2"));
es.submit(() -> System.out.println("Message 3"));
es.shutdown();
```

Comment: If I do that then the messages don't execute in the order I start the threads, e.g. the output should be "Message 1" then "Message 2" then "Message 3". They execute in a random order e.g. "Message 2", "Message 3", "Message 1". What I'm trying to say is how would I execute a runnable for each message in an executorservice such that the output is  in ascending order "Message 1" then "Message 2" then "Message 3" and not a random order such as "Message 2", "Message 3", "Message 1".

Comment: @RaeesSharif-Aamir I'm puzzled. Your question asks about multiple threads but it seems that you only want to do one thing at a time.

Comment: @David that's right. OP only need a single thread to execute several tasks, one aftwr another.

Comment: @RaeesSharif-Aamir Since the OP accepts this answer, I believe the question was mis-titled. (Or the answer is that it's very easy to join *all* the threads if there's only one of them.)

Comment: Don't forget to wait for the tasks to finish after the shutdown: `es.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)`. It has the same practical goal as the `join`.

Answer (score 7):

You can control sequential execution of threads using SingleThread ExecutorService with future.get() method.

**DummyTask Class**

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class DummyTask implements Callable<Integer>
{

int taskId;

public DummyTask(int taskId) {
    this.taskId = taskId;
}

@Override
public Integer call() throws Exception
{
    System.out.println("excuting task... Task Id: " + taskId);
    return taskId;
}

}
```

**SequentialExecution Class**

```
package com.amit.executorservice;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class SequentialExecution 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {

    DummyTask task1 = new DummyTask(1);
    DummyTask task2 = new DummyTask(2);
    DummyTask task3 = new DummyTask(3);
    Future<Integer> result = null;
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    result = executor.submit( task1 );
    // future.get() Waits for the task to complete, and then retrieves its result.
    result.get();

    result = executor.submit( task2 );
    // future.get() Waits for the task to complete, and then retrieves its result.
    result.get();

    result = executor.submit( task3 );
    // future.get() Waits for the task to complete, and then retrieves its result.
    result.get();

    executor.shutdown();

}
}
```

**Output**

```
excuting task... Task Id: 1
excuting task... Task Id: 2
excuting task... Task Id: 3
```

Output will always be same and all task will get executed in sequence.

Comment: The key here is `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, not the usage of `Future`.

Answer (score 3):

If you already use a thread pool in your application, you can reuse it by means of zero-threaded proxy serial executor, without creating special single threaded thread pool.
One implementation is described in the [javadoc section of Executor interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html), another, optimized implementation, at my Github repository [CodeSamples](https://github.com/akaigoro/CodeSamples/tree/master/src/simpleactor).